# User is not authorized after successful PasswordSignInAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity, react-redux, unauthorized

I use Postman to send request to /api/account/login and user logs in, then I send request to /api/account/logout and it logs out successfully, but when I do this in frontend, I fill in the log in form and send the request, I get response.ok, but when I try to send request to /api/account/logout it throws 401 Unauthorized.

I think there is a problem in my Startup.cs ConfigureServices method, but I'm not sure what it is

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(x => 
            x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RemoteConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext, int>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
        });


        // services.AddScoped<UserGroupRepository, UserGroupRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddScoped<ISurveysRepository, SurveysRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IUsersRepository, UsersRepository>();
    }        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true,
                ReactHotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
```

I noticed, when sending request using form that even here the user is not authorized

```
        [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginRequest request)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(request.UserName, request.Password, true, false);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new ErrorResponse
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Invalid User Name or Password."
            });
        }

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return NoContent();
        else
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

    }
```

Comment: And your Configure method? That's the interesting part, since there the middleware is registered and the order of registrations is important

Comment: I added the Configure method

Answer (score 0):

Was a mistake in my api.js performRequest method, I missed

```
credentials: 'include'
```